# ASP.NET Core 2.1 File Upload DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my controller code when I upload files. For some reason I am keep getting an this error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(UploadDocumentViewModel Input)
{
    var filePath = $"{this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}/documents";
    foreach(var item in Request.Form.Files)
    {
        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName;
        fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
        var fullFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        using(var stream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    return this.Ok();
}
```

This is the directory I am uploading to:

> 'C:\Users\uuu\Source\Repos\Applicat\Applicatto\wwwroot\documents\2018-10-27.png'.

To my understanding its saying that the path can't be found? But I have created the documents folder manually and this error still happens.

EDIT:

Top of the controller:

```
private readonly ILogger<DocumentsController> logger;
private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

public DocumentsController(ILogger<DocumentsController> logger, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the Controller or the service constructor which contains the `Save` method?

Comment: where did you create the directory ?

Comment: @TânNguyễn I have provided the constructor

Comment: @Shyju I created it in the wwwroot folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem came from getting the physical path.

Here is the normal way I usually use (*I've removed the logger because I don't use it in this example - just to make the code shorter, but you can define and use it again*):

```
public class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    // you should name the field(s) like this to make it/them difference
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public DocumentsController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Save(UploadDocumentViewModel Input)
    {
        // NOTE: we don't need "/" character before the path, like "/documents"
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "documents");

        // then, copy and paste your code to continue
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Since we use ASP.NET Core, we want to return `IActionResult` instead of `ActionResult`.